# How to prove this equality with the property of a convex function

Tags: inequality

I want to prove this inequality:
$$\frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}<\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2})$$
Using the fact that:
If f(x) is convex, then:
$$(b-a)f(\frac{a+b}{2})<\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx<(b-a)(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2})$$
by choosing suitable a,b&f(x).
I tried to choose $$f(x)=x, a=n-1, b=n$$. But, it seems to be wrong. Please share any thoughts and hints with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\right)
$$
to be
$$
(b-a)\left(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}\right) \, .
$$
That suggests to choose $a=n-1$, $b=n$, and $f(x) = 1/x^2$. Then
$$
(b-a)f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{(n-1/2)^2} = \frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}
$$
and
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac 1n
$$
so that we get exactly the desired result.